# How to fetch an api using axios?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5)
```

I'm new in react-native.
I want to know how to fetch the below api using `axios` in react-native.

What I am doing wrong here? I'm not able to fetch data in this way, why?

Thank You in advance!

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5")
    .then((data)=> {setData(data)})
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
  })

  console.log(data)
```

Comment: if I remember axios, you'd want `.then((result)=> {setData(result.data)})`

Comment: Can you point out that what is the issue you are facing? What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes in your code:

- when using `.then` in axios, use `response.data` for pointing to the actual data in the response.
- `useEffect` will execute based on its `dependency-arrays`, you should make sure that it is not going to re-render all the time, so, you pass a `[]` at the end of this hook to prevent re-rendering. (Becuase `[]` is an empty array which will never change!)

It may solve your problem:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5")
    .then((response)=> {setData(response.data)})
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
},[])

console.log(data)
```